# Copy text from CardView to Clipboard

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview, android-cardview

I have a `RecyclerView` and in each row, I have a `CardView`. I have three `TextView`s. I want to copy the text from one of the `TextView`s within the `CardView` during the `onClick` event. This is what I have so far:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView ora, onoma_xristi, minima;
    public CardView card;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        card = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.single_row_cardview);
        ora = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ora);
        onoma_xristi = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.onoma_xristi);
        minima = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.minima);

        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        ClipboardManager myClickboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", v.minima.getText());
        myClickboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);

    }
}
```

Is the code above correct? If not, any suggestions about why it may not be working?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Please specify what the issue is and what you are trying to achieve by copying it. Because if what you want is to get the text the ClipboardManager is completely unnecessary

Comment: I have a RecyclerView and in each CardView i have three TextViews. I want when i click on CardView to copy the content of one TextView in Clipboard. The errors i get (it's all red) is in getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
ClipboardManager myClickboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", minima.getText().toString());
        myClickboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), v.getResources().getString(R.string.antigrafike), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Ok. So it looks like you were trying to access the clipboard within another class. That is probably the reason why it wasn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the click functionality works, the clipboard implementation that you have is correct. You are missing one small thing:

```
ClipData myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", v.minima.getText().toString());
```

I think you forgot the `v.minima.getText().toString()` statement. `getText()` by itself won't return a `String` value. I'm pretty sure it will return a `CharSequence[]` value according to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html). Let me know how you go.

Comment: Thanks i did that but still i have errors in getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE)